# Problema de arreglos C++

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy ingresando pasando un `char` a un arreglo de `char` y al momento de insertar lo hace bien, pues ingreso e imprimo todo de poco a poco.

Luego hice otro `for` para mostrar solo el arreglo y resulta que solo me aguarda las últimas 5 letras de mi `char` en todo.

Es que el arreglo no se mantiene. Osea le meto información y cuando imprimo el arreglo me sale alterado el arreglo, rango 2 `for`: Uno agrega información al arreglo e imprime el arreglo cada ciclo y el otro `for` que se dedica a imprimir el mismo arreglo me imprime cosas muy diferentes, siendo el caso que los 2 son el mismo arreglo.

No sé que esta mal.

```
void Agregar(char Frase[], int Caracteres);
int main()
{
    string Texto;
    string Texto2;
    char Frase[180];

    cout<<"Ingresa La Palabra A Encriptar: ";
    getline(cin,Texto);

    for(int  i = 0; Texto[i] != 0;++i){
        if(Texto[i] != 32)
            Texto2 = Texto2 + Texto[i];
    }
    cout<<"Sin Espacios: "<<Texto2<<endl;

    int Num = Texto2.length();
    strcpy(Frase, Texto2.c_str());
    int CaracteresRest = 5-(Num%5);
    if (CaracteresRest==5)
    {
        CaracteresRest=0;
    }
    Agregar(Frase,CaracteresRest);
    Num = strlen(Frase);
    int Multiplo = Num/5;
    cout<<"Con *: "<<Frase<<endl;
    cout<<"**Arreglo**"<<endl;

    string * arreglo;
    arreglo = new string[Multiplo,5];
    string *arreglo2 = new string[Multiplo,5];

    int ContTex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Multiplo; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++){
            arreglo[i,j] = Frase[ContTex];
            ContTex = ContTex + 1;
            cout<< arreglo[i,j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<""<<endl;
    }
//    delete [] arreglo;
/**El arreglo que imprimo aqui es muy diferente al paso y eso no deberia de pasar**/
    cout<<""<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < Multiplo; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++){
            cout<< arreglo[i,j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<""<<endl;
    }



}

void Agregar(char Frase[], int Caracteres){
    int i=0;
    while (Frase[i]!='\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }
    int TamTotal=i+Caracteres;
    while (i<TamTotal)
    {
        Frase[i]='*';
        ++i;
    }
    Frase[i]='\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas reservas están mal:

```
arreglo = new string[Multiplo,5];
string *arreglo2 = new string[Multiplo,5];
```

El operador `new` tiene, de acuerdo a la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/), las siguientes sintaxis:

```
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size);
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) noexcept;
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
```

Y como ves no hay ninguna llamada que coincida, salvo la tercera opción, y no querrías que eso suciediese porque esta opción **no reserva memoria**, sino que inicializa los objetos en `ptr`, que en tu caso es `5`.

`new` **no permite** hacer reservas de matrices directamente. Para hacer esto tienes dos opciones:

- Haces una única reserva de "*filas*columnas*" elementos y gestionas esa región como una matriz. En este caso tienes que transformar la región lineal en una de dos dimensiones:

  ```
  char* array= new [Multiplo*5];

  char* elemento = &array[i*Multiplo];
  ```
- Haces dos reservas. En este caso la inicialización es más compleja pero el uso es más sencillo:

  ```
  char ** array= new char*[filas];
  for( int i=0; i<Multiplo; i++ )
    array[i] = new char[5];

  char* elemento = array[i];
  ```

En cualquier caso dudo que necesites una matriz de `string` sino, en tal caso, necesitarás una matriz de `char`.

Por otro lado no estás calculando `Multiplo` correctamente:

```
Num = strlen(Frase);
int Multiplo = Num/5;
```

¿Qué pasa si la longitud es 12? Multipló valdrá 2 y entonces dejarás 2 caracteres sin procesar...

Tienes que comprobar que el resto sea 0 y, si no es así, sumar uno a `Multiplo`.

Cuando decías

> al momento de insertar lo hace bien, pues ingreso e imprimo todo de poco a poco.

Te estabas engañando un poco, ya que únicamente estabas imprimiendo el carácter que acababas de almacenar, el cual, por lógica, va a ser correcto... pero con eso no estás comprobando si estás machacando algún carácter anterior. De ahí tu confusión inicial.

La función corregida:

```
int main()
{
    string Texto;
    string Texto2;
    char Frase[180];

    cout<<"Ingresa La Palabra A Encriptar: ";
    getline(cin,Texto);

    for(int  i = 0; Texto[i] != 0;++i){
        if(Texto[i] != 32)
            Texto2 = Texto2 + Texto[i];
    }
    cout<<"Sin Espacios: "<<Texto2<<endl;

    int Num = Texto2.length();
    strcpy(Frase, Texto2.c_str());
    int CaracteresRest = 5-(Num%5);
    if (CaracteresRest==5)
    {
        CaracteresRest=0;
    }
    Agregar(Frase,CaracteresRest);
    Num = strlen(Frase);
    int Multiplo = Num/5;
    if( Num % 5 != 0 ) Multiplo++;
    cout<<"Con *: "<<Frase<<endl;
    cout<<"**Arreglo**"<<endl;

    char *arreglo = new char[Multiplo*5];

    int ContTex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Multiplo; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++){
            arreglo[i*5+j] = Frase[ContTex];
            ContTex = ContTex + 1;
            cout<< arreglo[i*5+j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << '\n';
    for(int i = 0; i < Multiplo; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++){
            cout << arreglo[i*5+j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    delete[] arreglo;
}
```

Comment: Es usted muy amable, ya pude resolver mi problema, gracias :)